# How to disable template proposals in vscode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode suddenly shows me some texts where I can double click on it for adding it to my source file. In the image you can see concat! indexof! lastIndexOf!... etc
[image]

I don't know how to remove this. It is not actualy in the source file. There must be some extension in vscode which add this, but how can I find out which extension?

I hope somebody has got any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `Help: Start Extension Bisect` command would help you.  See [Resolving extension issues with bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect#:%7E:text=The%20Extension%20bisect%20utility%20in%20VS%20Code%20was,extensions%20installed%20and%20the%208th%20extension%20is%20%22bad%22.).

You would basically be disabling half your extensions at a time and look if that extra text is still produced - it won't take long to narrow down to the problematic extension.  It works well.